# The app metadata promotes another mobile platform

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have updated my app and published the update to Windows App store but during certification it fails by giving below reasons

> App Policies: 10.1 Inaccurate Representation Your app and its
>   associated metadata must accurately and clearly reflect the source,
>   functionality, and features of your app. All aspects of your app
>   should accurately describe the functions, features and any important
>   limitations of your app. Your app may not use a name or icon similar
>   to that of other apps. Your app may not claim to be to be from a
>   company, government body, or other entity if you do not have
>   permission to make that representation. Keywords may not exceed seven
>   unique terms and should be relevant to your app. Your app must be
>   fully functional. Locations: Metadata Notes To Developer The app
>   metadata promotes another mobile platform. For more information see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615230.

I don't know what happened to this update. Earlier versions were approved without any issue.

If anyone have any clue how to fix it , please please let me know.

Comment: Are some default blue X Xamarin icons maybe included in your app by any chance? That's the first thing that comes to mind.. Also check out the [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615230) that Microsoft themselves provide. The issue could be with your app icon not being 'fancy' enough.

Comment: With the current icons, app was approved on initial submission and 1 update with the same icon sets were also approved but this update with the same icon set fails certification.

Comment: Could be the check is only (re)enforced recently. Anyways, isn't there any way you can ask them for more information?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway the solution I rebuild and deployed again without any changes and this time it is certified without any issue.

Don't know what Microsoft was looking for.

Comment: If it is anything like Apple, different app testers can approve one app and the next time you submit it can get rejected again. It would be much better to find out what went wrong the last time so that the next time you have a deadline coming up to get your app out, it does not get rejected again.